# Is it possible to deploy war file into WebSphere 7?

Tags: java, websphere

I am able to deploy ear file into WAS 7. But for same project unable to deploy the war file into websphere 7. Is it possible to deploy war file into websphere 7?

Comment: It is possible to deploy war files in WAS7. Show us the error that you get while deploying.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend deploying your WAR file in EAR archive for WebSphere Application Server. Although WAS servers support deploying WAS from admin console (and not from IDE like Eclipse or RAD), after deploying such WAR, WAS packages it into automatically generated EAR. So WAS (and also some other servers like Weblogic) always in fact run EAR applications.

With deploying WAR you also have no influence on EAR level configuration as it is generated automatically on WAS.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere 7 is a Java-ee 5 application server and provides so both ejb and servlet container.
It's so indeed possible to deploy a war.

If your web-application (`war`) is part of your Java-ee application (`ear`) you have to package it inside the `ear`, otherwise you can deploy it alone.

See [packaging application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html)